# Continuity of matrix product with respect to matrix norm?

Tags: matrices, continuity, normed-spaces

I'm trying to teach myself about ordinary differential equations with an old script and I'm struggling with this problem:

Show that the matrix product is continuous with respect to
the matrix norm. That is, if $A_j → A$ and $B_j → B$ we have $A_j\cdot B_j → AB$.

My problem is that I don't even understand what the limit of $A_j\cdot B_j$ has to do with the matrix norm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To summarize the (good) answers you have already: A mapping is "continuous" if "nearby points map to nearby values". The matrix norm allows you to give precise meaning to "nearby". The upshot is, a matrix-valued function is continuous in this setting if and only if each entry is a continuous function of the inputs. The entries of a matrix product $AB$ are _polynomials_ in the entries of $A$ and $B$, hence continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Well you need a notion of norm in order to speak of convergence,i.e.

$$A_jB_j\longrightarrow AB\mathrm{\ \ iff\ \ }\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N>0\mathrm{\ s.t.\ }j>N\Rightarrow\Vert AB-A_jB_j\Vert<\epsilon$$

Anyway here you don't need to go back to the definition to prove that the product is continuous. You basically need properties which are easy to prove :

- The product on real/complex numbers is continuous
- The sum on real/complex numbers is continuous
- The projections ($f(x)=x_i$, $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$) on any coordinates of a vector are continuous
- The "suspension" ($f_i(x)=(0,...,x,...,0)$, $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$), that is, the function that associates a real number with a vector containing only zeros but $x$ at the i-th coordinate is also continuous
- Most important : if $f,g$ are two (composable) continuous functions, then their composition is also continuous.

With that being said, notice that the matrix product is but a composition of all these different functions which are all continuous.

Hence it's continuous.

Answer (score 3):

In general: continuity can be defined only for functions between topological spaces.

It seems that you refer to a definition of continuity in terms of limits, and this is usually done in a metric space (that is also a topological space) ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Continuous_maps)) .

A vector space of matrices as, for example, $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ (that is a vector space) becomes a metric space if we define  a norm that induce a distance in the canonical way:
$$
d(A,B)=||A-B||
$$
So, if we have a norm, we have metric space and we can define convergence and continuity.